# Detect for fullscreen from a service in android

Tags: java, android

I am creating a color picking feature that is able to pick color from anywhere on the android screen.

I am able to pick the color accurately however when an app gets into full screen, the calculations have to account for the system UI's height into the calculation.

```
if (fullScreenState == true)
    ycoord = ycoord + statusHeight;

int pixel = screen.getPixel(xcoord ,ycoord);
Log.d("pixel color", "Pixel Color: + " + Integer.toHexString(pixel) + " at x:" + xcoord + " y:" + ycoord);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a transparent view to the window manager, with 1px width and match_parent height. Then, add global layout listener to this view, and every time there's a change on the layout, just check for the position of this view on screen. If it's Y is 0, then the status bar is not visible, so a full screen app must be running.